# Recognise repeating number in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, repeat

I have a SQL Server column of type `int` that stores testscores from 10 to 550, but some testscores do not fit the range, e.g. 521521.

What I want is to take the repeating part of the number and save that. How can I do this in SQL ?

- `521521` should become `521`
- `919191` should become `91`
- `7676` should become `76`

I do not want to simply take the left (max) three spots or half of the string, as I also have data that says 123456, which of course should remain clear as unusable data. However, I am willing to take the risk for cases like 123123.

Therefore, I am really looking for something to recognise repeating numbers/letters.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Different products have different functions.

Comment: Thank you for your question. Sorry I missed that. I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: @MarjavanderWind SSMS is a frontend tool, not an RDBMS - you're actually using some edition and version of _SQL Server_ (or _Azure SQL_, or _Synapse_, or PDW, or Amazon Babelfish, or maybe even Sybase) - as all of those RDBMS implement TDS and so can be used with SSMS.

Comment: Please show use your `CREATE TABLE` statements: we need to see the exact data-type details of your columns: e.g. if they're `nvarchar` cols it's very different to `int` cols.

Comment: get the length , if even number, divide by 2 , check the first half to the second half, if the same drop the second half

Comment: @P.Salmon that would not work for the second case right?

Comment: That's true....

Comment: This is probably something you better do in a programming language rather than in T-SQL, but if you can't, than @P.Salmon has a pretty good start - for the second example, you'll have to see if you can divide the number of digits to three instead of to two and if so, are the 3 parts identical.

Comment: Perhaps you should also be looking to add a `CONSTRAINT` to your column to *stop* input of values < 10 and > 550. The use of a `smallint` (unfortunately `256` is too large for a `tinyint`) might also be a consideration, as then you can't store values like `521521`.

Comment: I wonder what you want expect to have for `111111`; should that be `11` or `111`?

Comment: It may be worth considering the first character as a kind of delimiter and since you only need to know the first 2 occurrences then splitting out the first 2 tokens on this basis ie 91,91 might do but you have to apply your knowledge of the data to say of this is worthwhile.

Comment: Can you explain how you end up with repeating data? Why not just prevent that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, string manipulation isn't T-SQL's strong suit, but I was curious as to how hard will it be to find a pure T-SQL solution for this.
My solution is quite cumbersome but it works for all the scenarios you've described and a few scenarios I came up with based on your question. (BTW, with regards to [Thom A's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76704556/recognise-repeating-number-in-sql-server/76705167#comment135232454_76704556) (expected result from 111111), it returns 111)

first, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @Demo AS TABLE 
(
  col int,
  expected int
);

INSERT INTO @Demo  (col, expected) VALUES
(521521, 521), -- repeat after 3 digits
(919191, 91), -- repeat after 2 digits, 3 times
(919291, 919291), -- no repeat - Note the 92 in the middle
(7676, 76), -- repeat after 2 digits
(123456, 123456), -- no repeat
(2147421474, 21474), -- repeat after 5 digits 
(2147483647, 2147483647), -- no repeat
(12341234, 1234), -- repeat after 4 digits
(123123123,123), -- repeat after 3 digits, 3 times
(123456123,123456123); -- no repeat
```

Note the comments - they specify why the expected result is what it is.

Then, the query: I've had to use quite a few `CROSS APPLY`s and a `CASE` expression, but it does provide the expected result:

```
SELECT col, expected,
       CASE WHEN HasTwoParts = 1 
                AND LEFT(StringCol, NumberOfDigits/2) = RIGHT(StringCol, NumberOfDigits/2) THEN LEFT(StringCol, NumberOfDigits/2)
            WHEN HasThreeParts = 1 
                AND LEFT(StringCol, NumberOfDigits/3) = RIGHT(StringCol, NumberOfDigits/3) 
                AND LEFT(StringCol, NumberOfDigits/3) = SUBSTRING(StringCol, (NumberOfDigits/3)+1, (NumberOfDigits/3)) THEN LEFT(StringCol, NumberOfDigits/3)
            WHEN HasFiveParts = 1 
                AND LEFT(StringCol, NumberOfDigits/5) = RIGHT(StringCol, NumberOfDigits/5) THEN LEFT(StringCol, NumberOfDigits/5)
            ELSE StringCol
       END As Result
FROM @Demo 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(col as varchar(12)) As StringCol) As AsString
CROSS APPLY (SELECT LEN(StringCol) As NumberOfDigits) As Length
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT IIF(NumberOfDigits % 2 = 0, 1, 0) As HasTwoParts, 
           IIF(NumberOfDigits % 3 = 0, 1, 0) As HasThreeParts,
           IIF(NumberOfDigits % 5 = 0, 1, 0) As HasFiveParts) As LengthDividers;
```

And the results:

```
col         expected    Result
------------------------------
521521      521         521
919191      91          91
919291      919291      919291
7676        76          76
123456      123456      123456
2147421474  21474       21474
2147483647  2147483647  2147483647
12341234    1234        1234
123123123   123         123
123456123   123456123   123456123
```

You can see a live demo on [<kbd>db<>fiddle</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/5mx09IVP)

Answer (score 3):

**You don't need string manipulation here.** You can do it with some modulo and integer division, and a big `CASE`

```sql
SELECT *,
  Corrected = CASE
    WHEN col / 100    % 100    = col % 100    AND col / 10000       IN (0, col % 100   )
      THEN col % 100
    WHEN col / 1000   % 1000   = col % 1000   AND col / 1000000     IN (0, col % 1000  )
      THEN col % 1000
    WHEN col / 10000  % 10000  = col % 10000  AND col / 100000000   IN (0, col % 10000 )
      THEN col % 10000
    WHEN col / 100000 % 100000 = col % 100000 AND col / CAST(10000000000 AS bigint) IN (0, col % 100000)
      THEN col % 100000
    ELSE col
  END
FROM @Demo d;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/Qgjnd6GV)

Comment: That's pretty neat, and has good performance

Comment: Doesn't work for this string though: 1010101010

Comment: Same principle https://dbfiddle.uk/u54ES_oK just gets a bit unwieldy (and non-deterministic as OP hasn't specified what result they want for `64646464` for example)

Comment: Yeah, that's a good answer. +1 from me as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another version:

```sql
DECLARE @data TABLE (n int, expected int)

INSERT INTO @data
VALUES  (521521, 521)
,   (919191, 91)
,   (7676, 76)
,   (123456, 123456)
,   (123123, 123)
,   (1234567, 1234567)
,   (111111111, 111)
,   (1111111111, 11111)
,   (1000011111, 1000011111)

SELECT  n, expected, actual
FROM    (

        SELECT  n, expected, actual
        ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY n
            ORDER BY CASE WHEN REPLICATE(actual, LEN(nString) / z.x) = nString THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC
            ,   CASE WHEN actual = nString THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC
            ,   LEN(actual) DESC
        ) sort
        FROM    @data d
        CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT  CAST(n AS VARCHAR(12)) AS nString
            ) n
        CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT  SUBSTRING(nString, 1, x.x) AS actual
                ,   x.x
                FROM    (
                    VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)
                ) x(x)
            ) z
        ) x
WHERE   x.sort = 1
```

What i do is take x number of characters from a string, and then trying to replicate these characters so they fill the string and trying to compare to the initial string. If it matches, it means string consist of repeating characters.

Finally, i sort them so we get most desired result, sorted by:

- repeated string being matched first
- but not non-repeating strings
- take the longest repeating string, this fixes problem with 11111111 strings, which technically repeat by "1", "11" and "1111"

Comment: Nice one! though one small thing: instead of casting the `int` to `nvarchar(max)` you can cast it to `varchar(12)` which is long enough to contain all the digits and the - sign of the smallest possible value of `int`.  +1 from me.

Comment: Thanks, i rewrote it a bit and moved cast to one place

Comment: @ZoharPeled You can do it without any string manipulation https://dbfiddle.uk/Qgjnd6GV